# Intersection of translations of irrationals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, irrational-numbers

Let $l>0$ and $\mathbb{Q}^c$ denotes set of irrationals. We define $$ E=\cap_{x\in(-l,l)}( \mathbb{Q}^c+x), $$
where $\mathbb{Q}^c+x=\{q+x:q\in\mathbb{Q}^c\}.$

Is it easy to show that $E$ cannot contains any rationals. Also $E$ cannot contains any real numbers from $(-l,l).$ So definitely $E\subseteq \mathbb{Q}^c\cap (-l,l)^c$.

My question:

1. Is $E$ non-empty?
2. Is $E$ has zero Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Just a tiny comment to help your exposition in the future: Please try to use $x\in X$, $y\in Y$ (rather than reversing and using $x\in Y$, for example). Since most people would think of $q\in\Bbb Q$, please use a different letter for an element of the complement, say $s\in\Bbb Q^c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E$ is empty. Let $\alpha$ be irrational. Since the rationals are dense, there exists $x$, $-\ell<x<\ell$, such that $\alpha-x$ is rational. Then $\alpha$ is not in ${\bf Q}^c+x$, so it's not in $E$.

A bit more detail: choose $n$ so $10^{-n}<\ell$, take $x<10^{-n}$ to have decimal expansion agreeing with that of $\alpha$ from the $n$th decimal place on. Then $\alpha-x$ is a terminating decimal, hence, rational.